# How do you calculate the real "impact force" of a low mass but fast moving object?

Tags: forces, energy, energy-conservation, velocity

I have a question about "sandblasters" and further more about high velocity sand grains.

Sandblasters are really efficient to get rid of rust on steel.
The ejection velocity of the sand grains is (by manufacturer description) 300 m/s .

I used formular for kinetic energy is: $E = 0.5 \cdot m \cdot v^2 $

That means that a sand grain with the avg. mass of 100mg would have a kinetic energy of 4.5 Joule. Which is not that much energy.
But if I calculate the impact force, I always get a ridiculously high "impact force".

I used this online calculator:
https://www.gigacalculator.com/calculators/impact-force-calculator.php

Which uses the formular:
$$ 
F_{avg}=(\frac{0.5 \cdot m \cdot v^2}{d})
$$

Which also has the disclaimer:

> The impact formula has decent accuracy, but just as any physical model is just an approximation.

In a estimation I assumed that the "deformation distance" for the sandblasted grain would be 0.1mm .

Which would lead to a impact avg. force of: **45 kN**

Which would be equivalent of a 4588kg heavy object on a surface area of a grain of sand.
This sounds to me like a ridiculous overestimation.

How to factor in energy transformation properly?
Like deformation and resulting heat?

What would be the steps to get a propper estimation on how the energy is converted on impact, and what the realistic impact force would be?

I assume that the material of the sandgrain and impact surface would also be important.

When I extrapolate my mind Game:
Now lets say I have a "small particle Railgun" that ejects the 100mg sandgrain with a velocity of 15000km/h (~4166m/s) which would result in the kinetic energy of the sandgrain of 867 Joule. What would forces and energies are to expect?

My naive amateur Opinion:
If I play this scenario in my head, I would assume, it could penetrate a human body but could not make a dent into steel, but would create a large ammount of heat on impact while shattering the sand grain, if the grain of sand would be regular quartz sand.

Comment: For one thing, it looks like you are overestimating the mass of a grain of sand. According to this: https://www.themeasureofthings.com/results.php?comp=weight&unit=gms&amt=0.0044&sort=pr&p=1#:~:text=With%20tremendous%20variety%20in%20the,an%20average%20of%200.0044%20grams. The mass is 4.4 mg which brings your force down to about 2 kN.

Comment: Yes. But I mean really with sand blasters, you get abrasives with defined weights in sandblasters. You can choose materials from glas to sand, to epoxy and to silicon stone. You can choose grain density. But lets run with the 100mg grain , because thats what's witten on the abrasives. 2 kN is still 203KG placed on a suface area of a grain of sand, which is still high and over estimated. How to estimate correclty?

Comment: Your problem cones from trying to put all forced in terms of weight. There is nothing intrinsically wrong about these numbers. The impact effect of a bullet is not the same as of a large weight sitting on your chest.